# Windows 10のPackageManagement（旧OneGet）からChocolateyを利用したい

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, chocolatey

Windows 10のマシンにChocolateyを入れようと思い、まず10でちゃんと使えるかどうかググったところ、Windows 10 TPからPowerShellから使えるOneGetというパッケージマネージャが導入され、リリース版ではそれがPackageManagementという名前に変わったことを知りました。

OneGetの頃はChocolateyのリポジトリを利用することもできたようなのですが、リリース版になって削除された？らしく、ググった限りの方法では利用できません。

PackageManagementからChocolateyを使うにはどのような手順を踏めば良いのでしょうか？

関連してそうな各コマンドの結果は下記のとおりです。

```
PS C:\> Get-Command -Module PackageManagement

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Find-Package                                       1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Get-Package                                        1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Get-PackageProvider                                1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Get-PackageSource                                  1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Install-Package                                    1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Register-PackageSource                             1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Save-Package                                       1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Set-PackageSource                                  1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Uninstall-Package                                  1.0.0.0    PackageManagement
Cmdlet          Unregister-PackageSource                           1.0.0.0    PackageManagement


PS C:\> Find-Package
警告: Unable to find package provider 'NuGet'.
警告: 指定された PackageManagement プロバイダー 'NuGet' は使用できません。
PS C:\> Get-PackageProvider

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
Programs                 10.0.10240.16384 {IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent}
msu                      10.0.10240.16384 {}
msi                      10.0.10240.16384 {AdditionalArguments}
PSModule                 1.0.0.0          {PackageManagementProvider, Location, InstallUpdate, InstallationPolicy...}


PS C:\> Get-PackageSource

Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  IsRegistered IsValidated  Location
----                             ------------     ---------  ------------ -----------  --------
PSGallery                        PSModule         False      True         False        https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/


PS C:\> Get-PackageSource -ProviderName chocolatey
警告: Unable to find package provider 'chocolatey'.
Get-PackageSource : Unable to find package providers (chocolatey).
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ Get-PackageSource -ProviderName chocolatey
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...etPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-PackageSource]、Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownProviders,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.GetPackageSource
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get-packageprovider chocolatey
```

でPackageProviderを追加すると、chocolateyが利用できるようです。

```
find-package -provider chocolatey notepad2
install-package notepad2
```

参考URL:
[OneGet (it's in the Windows 10 Preview!)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224000526/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/garretts/archive/2015/01/27/oneget-and-the-windows-10-preview.aspx)

Comment: あれっ、できました！　以前試したと思ったんだけどな……
ありがとうございました！